# Sorting of patterns and their representation with R

Tags: r, sorting, plot

I would like to create a plot with three graphics whose axis labels are the same. I have used the following code and data:

```
p1 <- apply(tabelle_fertig1, 2, mean)
p1 <- p1[sort(names(p1))]
p2 <- apply(tabelle_fertig2, 2, mean)
p2 <- p2[sort(names(p2))]
p3 <- apply(tabelle_fertig3, 2, mean)
p3 <- p3[sort(names(p3))]

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
barplot(p1, xlab = "PATTERN",log="y")
barplot(p2, xlab = "PATTERN",log="y")
barplot(p3, xlab = "PATTERN",log="y")
```

With this I get the graphic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIrRe.png)

That actually looks quite good, but I still want it to look nicer now. So I sort by the size of the values:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
barplot(sort(p1, decreasing = T), xlab = "PATTERN",log="y")
barplot(sort(p2, decreasing = T), xlab = "PATTERN",log="y")
barplot(sort(p3, decreasing = T), xlab = "PATTERN",log="y")
```

And then get the graphics:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V26fn.png)

How do I get it right now that the x-axes all have the same order of labeling, as in the first image but still look as beautiful as in the second image?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Comparing both results, the design stays exactly the same... the only reason why it looks nice is because it is sorted in a decreasing fashion. Thus, if you keep the same order of labeling you'd return to your first case (??)

Comment: Okay, can I somehow say that he should keep the first order from the first plot of the second image? So there's no other way? Because I would like to compare the plots with each other, but this is very difficult in the first picture.

Comment: the reason why it looks nice in the second case is because it is sorted. You could maybe sort one of them and sort the other two the same way. But these latter two will obviously not be in a totally decreasing fashion.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want, but how do I get it in R?

Comment: use the `order` function. It gives you the order by index. Then use the same order for all three vectors. So: `order_p1=order(p1); p1=p1[order_p1]; p2=p2[order_p1]; p3=p3[order_p1]`